# Javascript updates not reflecting on site - possibly cloudflare related

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I have made some changes to my javascript files and when in testing mode all works as expected, however when I upload the files the javascript changes do not work. I believe this is to do with Cloudflare for two reasons. firstly because I uploaded the exact same files to a different domain that is not under Cloudflare and the javascript changes worked as expected. Secondly, I turned on rocket loader yesterday and it seems too coincidental to not be related.

I have now turned off rocket loader but still the same problem :(

Does anyone have any suggestions and also does anyone have an idea of how long it takes Cloudflare setting changes to reflect on a site?

Really grateful to anyone out there who can help a fellow developer

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser cache, Ctrl + F5 to force clear and reload? Also what provider do you have for the site?

Comment: Yep tried that, completely cleared out the cache but still the same problem arrrggghhh! :(

Comment: On Cloudflare, you should see the option to "Purge", similar to cache except it will remove old caches instantly. See if you can find that under Cloudflare.